# Periodic shutdown with popup-message and skip/delay-button

Tags: debian, cron, shutdown

I want a computer (Debian, XFCE) to shutdown every day at

1. a **specific time** as well as
2. a **pop-up window** in advance telling about the immanent shutdown with, say *OK*, *Skip* and *Delay 60 min* buttons.

I noticed `xmessage` being installed and it gives an easy way to handle rudimentary pop-ups with defined buttons. But the workaround with `sed` on the crontab (to alter the event) and `service cron reload` (with the appropriate rights in `/etc/sudoers`) with all the exceptions I have to capture seems too fiddly.

Any ideas?

**P.s.:** `shutdown`'s own messages are not being read since the users are usually not on the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider a slightly different approach: instead of using `cron` for a shutdown, use `cron` to display a message with `xmessage`.

Then, after the actions (if any) taken from `xmessage` events (buttons pressed or not), you initiate a shutdown.

In other words:

- at a certain time, display `xmessage` via `cron`
- if no action is taken (button pressed) after a certain time - shutdown
- if button **is** pressed, delay shutdown with whatever time.

I wrote something similar to your needs in **[this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313814/191550)**.